# Python - Method Chaining with instances from different Classes

Tags: python, method-chaining

I know how to implement method chaining in Python within a single class, but I'm wondering if there is a way to chain methods from different classes, something like:

```
class C1:

    def sayHello(self):

        print "hello from c1"

        return self

class C2:

    def sayHello(self):

        print "hello from c2"

        return self

c1 = C1()

c2 = C2()

(c1.sayHello()).(c2.sayHello())

Output:
hello from c1
hello from c2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish here? like why? have you tried running it?

Comment: Yeh I tried, obviously it doesn't work. My goal is to chain methods from different classes.

Comment: +1, You can do it, as long as your methods return the other object. See my answer.

Comment: I see someone voted to close, but I think it's quite clear what was being asked. Is there anything further I can answer?

Comment: Thanks, your answer makes me understand how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can abstract this into a base class (to avoid repeating yourself) and then, as long as they know each other, you can approximate what you originally wanted:

```
class Base(object):

    def sayHello(self, other=None):
        print("hello from {self} to {other}".format(self=self, other=other))
        return other
    def __str__(self):
        return type(self).__name__

class C1(Base):
    '''C1!'''

class C2(Base):
    '''C2!'''

c1 = C1()
c2 = C2()

c1.sayHello(c2).sayHello(c1)
```

prints:

```
hello from C1 to C2
hello from C2 to C1
```

Answer (score 0):

Method chaining is usually only found in APIs where it makes it convenient to perform a sequence of actions on a single object.  The question of how to do it with two objects would really depend on how that was meaningful in your API or library.  That being said, here's one idea which is completely abstract:

```
# Untested code

class OtherChain(object):
    def __init__(self, other=None):
        self._other = other

    def sayHello(self):
        print "hello from {0}".format(type(self).__name__)
        return self._other

class C1(OtherChain):
    pass

class C2(OtherChain):
    pass

c2 = C2()
c1 = C1(c2)

c1.sayHello().sayHello()

# Output:
# hello from C1
# hello from C2
```

Of course this code has issues since doing `c1.sayHello().sayHello().sayHello()` would cause an `AttributeError` (I think).  Those kinds of details would probably get worked out if this code had some kind of context in a library where it was more meaningful.